# How to create DateTimeZone object from time zone string?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

Is there a way to create a (joda) DateTimeZone object from a time zone string representation, like "EDT", or "+0330"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Joda APIs do not support mapping of abbreviated timezone names (like "EDT").

Why?

Because they are ambiguous!  For instance EDT can mean either UTC-4 or UTC+11.

So if you want to implement a mapping, you need to decide how *you* want the names to be mapped, and then create and populate a map yourself.

Source:  http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/

Answer (score 6):

It's perhaps worth pointing out that, whilst jodatime does not support three-letter time zone identifiers (aside from "UTC"), `java.util.TimeZone` does; and you can create a `DateTimeZone` instance from a `TimeZone`, using the [`DateTimeZone.forTimeZone` method](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#forTimeZone-java.util.TimeZone-):

```
DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("..."))
```

**BUT** `TimeZone` doesn't support "EDT" either. From the Javadoc:

> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, their use is deprecated...

Note the "some": at the time of writing, PDT is not listed in `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` (on ideone.com, at least). If you try to use "PDT" here, you will [end up with the GMT timezone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.lang.String-):

> [`TimeZone.getTimeZone` returns] the specified TimeZone, or the GMT zone if the given ID cannot be understood.

So this approach is best avoided, unless you can guarantee that you will only ever try to use it for supported time zone identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for getting DateTimeZone object -

```
//User Defined
        DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
        //System Default TimeZone
        DateTimeZone dtzz = DateTimeZone.forID(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

Comment: that's not what the question stipulates

Comment: Sorry, By passing EDT/IST it is not possible. You have to get the string ID for the Country or place.

Comment: I see - the other answer explains why. Also, I figured a workaround: just prepend "GMT" to a string formatted like "+0330", and voila! `TimeZone.getTimeZone(str)` works :)